# Javascript if statement for if user has input type clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following input type:

```
<input type="text" id="textid">
```

and I want to make it so if the user clicks it, or if it is currently clicked or selected, it will alert "clicked". I tried doing this, but it didn't work.

```
$('#textid').focus(function() {
    alert('Function is clicked.');
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing nothing wrong if:

you used:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
```

and...

```
jQuery(function( $ ){ // (DOM is now ready and $ alias secured)

     // ...placed your code here

});
```

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/roqeda/2/edit?html,css,js,output)***

Answer (score 1):

With that code, the alert form will be appeared consecutively. I think you should create a handle function before, then bind it when `focusout` and unbind it when `focus`. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tmvan19/vcqLcybq/)